# How to hook Luis into a Bot Framework FormDialog

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a Dialog class which is a FormDialog (say, FormDialog< SandwichOrder>; one which builds an order for a sandwich, as per the bot framework documentation website). The SandwichOrder includes a "Price" property.

I also have a Dialog class which derives from LuisDialog which gets the price (based on, say, the size and/or province).

How can I hook [Luis](http://luis.ai) functionality into a Form Dialog?

Answer (score 3):

Currently it is not possible to call a Dialog in a form field step. But you can have your custom implementation of IRecognize for a Field in the form (in this case "Price") and in the `IEnumerable<TermMatch> Matches(string input, object defaultValue = null)` implementation call into your Luis model and return all the possible TermMatches based on the detected entities by Luis.

Comment: do you know if this functionality is being built in at all? 

It does seem a bit clunky to create our own custom fields simply for the purpose of jumping out to check a LuisIntent as well.

Comment: It is definitely in the backlog. I suggest add this as an idea to the [bot builder feedback](https://feedback.botframework.com/forums/354222-bot-builder-sdk) site, so other people can vote for it.

Comment: Would love to submit it as an idea (think I may have already done so) But I since noticed that https://feedback.botframework.com/ is 'retired'. Any idea where it moved to?

Answer (score 1):

This post: [Custom fields with FormBuilder in the Microsoft Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361918/custom-fields-with-formbuilder-in-the-microsoft-bot-framework?rq=1) appears to suggest an answer, and a way to implement your own custom field which implements IRecognizer. I haven't gotten it to work yet though.